# Javadoc linking to split package

Tags: java-8, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, jsr305

When using the javadoc tool (Which I do through the Maven Javadoc Plugin, not with javadoc directly), there is the `-link` option to link to external sources.  The problem now is that my project makes use of JSR-305 annotations, and I have configured the javadoc tool to link to the Java SE 8 APIs.

Both the Java SE 8 APIs and JSR-305 use `javax.annotation`, and so because javadoc can't really tell if `javax.annotation.Nullable` is from Java SE 8 or from JSR-305, it may generate a dead link to the Java SE 8 javadocs as opposed to a working link to the JSR-305 javadocs.  Is there a way to configure javadoc to fix this, such that links to `javax.annotation.Nullable` is linked to JSR-305 javadocs and other things like `javax.annotation.Resource` is lined to the Java SE 8 API?

Comment: Afaik, the decision is package based, i.e. there is a file “`package-list`” at the link target location which will be read. Thus, a class-based choice is not possible with this version of `javadoc`.